# can a windows service run a TCP server?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, service, tcp, windows-services

I created 2 programs in c++ using visual studio 2008: a windows service based on this [service](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948) which i added tcp server code to and a client program using MFC, which has a listbox that displays the ip address and hostname of the computer thats running the service. The user then chooses a server and clicks a connect button. Since there will be many servers running, I used some PHP script on a web host site. The service sends its ip address and host name to the web host, the web host puts the information into a list and the client then accesses this list.

all this works fine with the server code but when i put the server code into the windows service, the client program freezes and doesn't respond when the connect button is clicked. The ip address and host name still appear in the client listbox, i just can't connect to the server i select.

is the windows service stopping the server code from working?
here is the cpp file that contains the server code in the service program:

```
    char* WebPost(char Website[], char Webpage[], char Request[], int RetLen) 
{
    // Sends an HTTP Post request with POST Data...

    SOCKET WebSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    struct hostent *WebHost;
    WebHost = gethostbyname(Website);
    if (WebHost == NULL) 
    {
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSANOTINITIALISED)
            printf("Error Not Connected!");
        else
            printf("Error: %d", WSAGetLastError());

        Sleep(1000);
        exit(0);

    }

    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port   = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)WebHost->h_addr);
    connect(WebSocket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));


    char PostRequest[1024];

    sprintf(PostRequest,
        "POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: %s\r\n"
        "Content-Length: %hu\r\n"
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
        "\r\nD=%s\0",
        Webpage, Website,
        strlen(Request)+2, Request
    );

    send(WebSocket, PostRequest, strlen(PostRequest), 0);


    // Get return data 

    char* Data = new char[RetLen];
    recv(WebSocket, Data, 4, 0);

    for (;;) 
    {                           // Skip HTTP headers
        Data[0] = Data[1];
        Data[1] = Data[2];
        Data[2] = Data[3];

        recv(WebSocket, &Data[3], 1, 0);

        if (Data[0] == '\r' && Data[1] == '\n'
        &&  Data[2] == '\r' && Data[3] == '\n')
            break;

    }

    int DataLen = recv(WebSocket, Data, RetLen, 0);
    Data[DataLen] = '\0';   // Return the data

    shutdown(WebSocket, 2);
    closesocket(WebSocket);
    return Data;

}

void ServStart() 
{
    WSADATA wsaData; 

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }


    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) 
    {
        printf("The dll do not support the Winsock version %u.%u!\n", LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion),HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion));
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    //Start listening      
    ListeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (ListeningSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
        printf("Error at socket, error code: %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        printf("bind failed. Error code: %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListeningSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    if (listen(ListeningSocket, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        printf("listen: Error listening on socket %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListeningSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    char ac[80];
    if (gethostname(ac, sizeof(ac)) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        printf("Error when getting local host name: ", WSAGetLastError()); 
        exit(0);
    }

    struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(ac);
    if (phe == 0) 
    {
        printf("Error: ", WSAGetLastError()); 
        exit(0);
    }

    struct in_addr addr;
    memcpy(&addr, phe->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(struct in_addr)); // use the first ip-address
    printf("IP used by Server: %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr)); // inet_ntoa(addr) provides the local address.
    MyIP = inet_ntoa(addr);

    char SendBuf[32];
    // * is used as a separator, because it's not allowed in the hostname. 
    //So it won't interfere with it. 
    sprintf(SendBuf, "%hhu|%s*%s", cAddIP, MyIP, ac);   // Send the server the IP and host name
    WebPost(WEBSITE, WEBPAGE, SendBuf, 0);

    printf("listening for connections...\n\n");
}


void ShutDown()             // Shut down the server (tells the web server I am offline)
{
    char SendBuf[32];       // Remove my IP from the list of online servers...
    char ac[80];
    if (gethostname(ac, sizeof(ac)) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        printf("Error when getting local host name: ", WSAGetLastError()); 
        exit(0);
    }
    sprintf(SendBuf, "%hhu|%s*%s", cRemIP, MyIP,ac);
    WebPost(WEBSITE, WEBPAGE, SendBuf, 0);

    printf("Successful shutdown\n");
    Sleep(1000);

    WSACleanup();
}



void ServLoop() 
{
    SOCKADDR_IN SenderInfo;
    SOCKET NewConnection;

    int ByteReceived, nlen;
    char recvbuff[1024];

    for (;;) 
    {       
        //Main program loop
        NewConnection = SOCKET_ERROR;
        while(NewConnection == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            NewConnection = accept(ListeningSocket, NULL, NULL);    // this is a blocking function
            printf("New client got connected, ready to receive and send data...\n\n");

            ByteReceived = recv(NewConnection, recvbuff, sizeof(recvbuff), 0);

            if (ByteReceived > 0) 
            {
                getsockname(ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ServerAddr, (int *)sizeof(ServerAddr));

                memset(&SenderInfo, 0, sizeof(SenderInfo));
                nlen = sizeof(SenderInfo);

                getpeername(NewConnection, (SOCKADDR *)&SenderInfo, &nlen); 
            }

        }

        if (shutdown(NewConnection, 2) != 0)
            printf("there is something wrong with the shutdown. The error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        else
            printf("shutdown is working...\n");

    }

}

// --------------------------------------------

BOOL ConsoleProc(DWORD Msg) 
{
    switch (Msg) 
    {
        case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
        case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
            ShutDown();
        return false;
    }

    return false;
} 

// -----------------------------------------------------


CSampleService::CSampleService(PWSTR pszServiceName, 
                                BOOL fCanStop, 
                                BOOL fCanShutdown, 
                                BOOL fCanPauseContinue) :
    CServiceBase(pszServiceName, fCanStop, fCanShutdown, fCanPauseContinue),
    m_dwTimeout(10 * 1000)
{
    // Create a manual-reset event that is not signaled at first to indicate 
    // the service is stopping.
    m_hStoppingEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (m_hStoppedEvent == NULL)
    {
        throw GetLastError();
    }

    // Create a manual-reset event that is not signaled at first to indicate 
    // the stopped signal of the service.
    m_hStoppedEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (m_hStoppedEvent == NULL)
    {
        throw GetLastError();
    }
}


CSampleService::~CSampleService(void)
{
    if (m_hStoppedEvent)
    {
        CloseHandle(m_hStoppedEvent);
        m_hStoppedEvent = NULL;
    }

    if (m_hStoppingEvent)
    {
        CloseHandle(m_hStoppingEvent);
        m_hStoppingEvent = NULL;
    }
}

void CSampleService::OnStart(DWORD dwArgc, LPWSTR *lpszArgv)
{
    WriteErrorLogEntry(L"CSampleService::Start: function entry");

    // Log a service start message to the Application log.
    WriteEventLogEntry(L"CppWindowsService in OnStart", EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);

    // Queue the main service function for execution in a worker thread.
    CThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(&CSampleService::ServiceWorkerThread, this);

    WriteErrorLogEntry(L"CSampleService::Start: function exit");
}

void CSampleService::ServiceWorkerThread(void)
{
    WriteErrorLogEntry(L"CSampleService::ServiceWorkerThread: running");


    // Periodically check if the service is stopping.
    while (WaitForSingleObject(m_hStoppingEvent, m_dwTimeout) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
         // Perform main service function here...

        // Handle console events
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)ConsoleProc, TRUE);
        ServStart();            // Main loop is in another thread
        ServLoop();             // The never returning server loop

    }

    // Signal the stopped event.
    SetEvent(m_hStoppedEvent);
    WriteErrorLogEntry(L"CSampleService::ServiceWorkerThread: done");
}

void CSampleService::OnStop()
{
    ShutDown(); //shut down server

    SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, ERROR_SUCCESS, 30 * 1000);

    WriteErrorLogEntry(L"CSampleService::Stop: function entry");

    // Log a service stop message to the Application log.
    WriteEventLogEntry(L"CppWindowsService in OnStop", EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);

    // Indicate that the service is stopping and wait for the finish of the 
    // main service function (ServiceWorkerThread).
    SetEvent(m_hStoppingEvent);
    if (WaitForSingleObject(m_hStoppedEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, ERROR_INVALID_DATA, 30 * 1000);
        WriteErrorLogEntry(L"OnStop: Service Start", GetLastError());
        throw GetLastError();
    }

    WriteErrorLogEntry(L"CSampleService::Stop: function exit");
```

}

Comment: How else would the other network services run, if not as a service? You might want to add logging to the server program, to see what happens in it. And no, the normal `printf` function will not work as there is no console attached to `stdout`, you would either log to a file (preferably with date and time stamps) or use the Windows system log facility.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Which part of it isn't working correctly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i know printf functions don't work, i haven't changed all the server code yet.

Comment: @RobKennedy i am not sure what part exactly isn't working. all the server code (the top half of the code) works fine. but now that its in the windows service program it doesn't work

Comment: i know the web host code works fine because the ip address and hostname of the server appear in the client listbox. i think the problem is with ServLoop function, since the problem is when the client tries to connect to the server

Comment: Right. So which part of that code doesn't work? Use your debugging skills to narrow down the problem. Stack Overflow isn't here to debug your code for you.

Comment: @RobKennedy ok i debugged the program and found that it wasn't going into the ByteReceived if statement of the ServLoop function (its about half way down in the code i posted). i don't know why this isn't working because this worked fine before i added it into the service

Comment: In other words, your call to `recv` isn't returning a value greater than zero. So what *is* it returning? [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121.aspx) describes how to interpret non-positive return values.

Comment: that document didn't help. it didn't mention non-positive return values

Comment: Of course it does. Don't let it bite you. "If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero.
Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError."

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific question is, yes, a windows service can run a TCP server.

The answer to why yours does not work is not clear.  At first glance the service code looks reasonable.  It's possible connections to your service are being blocked by your OS firewall (i.e. your console one is in the accept list but your service one is not).  You might convert some of your error `printf` logic into something that prints to a file instead (e.g. `fprintf`?) so you can take a look at what's going on...

Comment: no the problem isn't the firewall. I added the program to the accepted list. please see my reply to Rob Kennedy's comment

Comment: did you get past the `accept` but not past the `recv`?  also it doesn't look like you're checking that `NewConnection` is a valid socket handle...

Comment: no i didn't get passed accept. it goes into the while but doesn't run the accept code

Comment: which means the server never sees an incoming connection.  this still "smells" of a firewall or permissions kind of issue.  are you sure you added the exact full path of the service executable that's running to the firewall (and not some other path, like your development one)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, of course it can.  Why would it not be possible?

Comment: One very obvious reason: the service is running on one of the `Network Restricted` accounts, which are introduced with Vista specifically to make this impossible. I.e. config error.

Comment: @MSalters no i am using the local account

Comment: @user2478375: There are two, `LocalSystem` and `LocalService`.